# How to select from a vector of fractions and respect the number of elements?

Tags: rounding, floor, ceil

I have a vector of fractions `a = [0.04352034965262487, 0.480655360084497, 0.02655889003246612, 0.449265400230412, 0.0]` of type `float64` such that of course `sum(a)=1`. These fractions represent persentages of some number `K=128`. So, multiplying `a` by `K` we obtain the number of elements in each fraction `a*K =[5.570604755535983, 61.523886090815616, 3.3995379241556636, 57.50597122949274, 0.0]`.

I want to transform this vector `a*K` into an `int` vector and respect the sum of elements of `a*K` to be `K`. What I am doing is `floor` but this will give `126` and not `128`. When I do `round` I obtain `129` and when I do `ceil` I obtain `130`.

I thought of applying `ceil` and then remove randomly the 2 elements that exceeds `128`. Is there a better way?

Comment: is this python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by first applying floor to `a*K` then pick `n` items that had the largest fractional parts and add one to them, where `n` is `K - sum(floor(a*K))`

In Python:

```
from math import floor

aK = [5.570604755535983, 61.523886090815616, 3.3995379241556636, 57.50597122949274, 0.0]
K = 128

# Sum of floored is less than K.
floored = [floor(x) for x in aK]
print(floored, sum(floored))

# Add 1 to each items with largest fractional part
frac = [x - y for x, y in zip(aK,floored)]
frac_rank = sorted(range(len(frac)), key=frac.__getitem__, reverse=True)
for i in frac_rank[:K - sum(floored)]:
    floored[i] += 1

# Now floored adds up to K
print(floored, sum(floored))
```